# Running a python code using process builder Java

Tags: java, python, bash, processbuilder

I need some help.
I am trying to run a python script called mantime.py from a directory. I've tried to google it and found several ways to do it. Yet, I still got 2 as the exit value, which I expect it 0 (terminate normally). Here is my code:

```
public int performedManTime() throws IOException, InterruptedException{
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/python","/Users/ab/Downloads/ManTIME/mantime.py","-ppp","test",inputDir.getAbsolutePath(),"i2b2");
        Map<String,String>env = pb.environment();
        env.put("MANTIME_CRF_TRAIN", "/usr/local/Cellar/crf++/0.58/bin/crf_learn");
        env.put("MANTIME_CRF_TEST", "/usr/local/Cellar/crf++/0.58/bin/crf_test");
        env.put("MANTIME_CORENLP_FOLDER","/Users/ab/Downloads/ManTIME/externals/stanford-corenlp-full-2014-08-27");
        Process process = pb.start();
        process.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Exit Value: "+process.exitValue());
        return process.exitValue();
    }
-ppp, test, input.dir and i2b2 are the arguments for the mantime.py
```

I tried to set up the environment as we can see above. Does anyone knows what are the problems? Any comment or suggestion would be really appreciated. Thank you

EDIT: I suspect since the python is on different directory with my tool (/usr/local/python). After I put the code bellow, somehow it works.

```
ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/python","/Users/ab/Downloads/ManTIME/mantime.py","-ppp","test",inputDir.getAbsolutePath(),"i2b2");
pb.directory(/myToolsDir)
```

Comment: check what was displayed in the `ErrorStream`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect since the python is on different directory with my tool (/usr/local/python). After I put the code bellow, somehow it works. Thank you guys

```
ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/python","/Users/ab/Downloads/ManTIME/mantime.py","-ppp","test",inputDir.getAbsolutePath(),"i2b2");
pb.directory(/myToolsDir)
```